# How to programmatically clear a cached View in Drupal 7?

Tags: caching, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

In Drupal 7 Views 3 how do I programmatically clear the cache of a view I've created?

I don't want to clear all caches or even all views caches, just a specific view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cache_clear_all('field:node:' . $node->nid, 'cache_field');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may delete it from database or use Drupal Cache API.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache) you have info about many different ways to clear cache.